# Programatically set Focus to a TextBox in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

In a Windows Phone app I have an `TextBox` and a `Button`. The user writes some text to the TextBox and taps the Button, the text from the TextBox is added to a list. The TextBox loses focus after the Button is tapped.

What I want to do is to set the focus back to the TextBox after the Button is tapped so the user can continue writing another text without needing to tap the TextBox.

I tried calling the `Focus()` method of the TextBox in the Button handler but this does not work. is there another, if any, way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Button clicked try to add `bollean flag = true`. Then check this flag on event `OnTextBoxLostFocus`.

```
<TextBox x:Name="tb" Grid.Row="1" LostFocus="Tb_OnLostFocus"/>
<Button x:Name="btn" Click="Btn_OnClick" />

 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private bool flag;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Btn_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        flag = true;
        tb.Focus();
    }

    private void Tb_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!flag) return;
        tb.Focus();
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

Hope its help.

Comment: it works when I have a few breakpoints set but not woithout them. I think there may be some kind of a delay (OnTextBoxLostFocus is fired before the flag is set to true).

Comment: For some reason the OnLostFocus is called twice. I changed the flag to a int and set it to 2 in click event and then in OnLostFocus I check if it is greater then zero and decrement id by 1. Strange, but works now.

Answer (score 5):

I have tried a lot of solutions, but this is the only one that works for me (Windows Phone 8.1 app).
First catch your TextBox's `Loaded` event, then call `Focus(FocusState.Keyboard)`.

```
private void myTextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myTextBox.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even I tried with lots of above solutions but none of them worked for me as am trying to focus on page load. Finally I got this solution and it worked.

```
private void txtBox_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtBox.Focus();
        }
```

Comment: Problem with this approach is that it only works if there is only one textbox. Should there be more (e.g. username and password), you cannot switch from one to another, as the focus stays in the first TextBox.

Comment: @kibitzerCZ good one, may be some one will work around this issue.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you call:

```
yourTextBox.Select(0,0)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.select.aspx

Comment: Can you show your code? I tried on a wp7 project and I tried to use in the click event of my button to call myTextBox.Focus() and it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can accomplish this by programmatically giving it focus. This can be done by
calling its Focusmethod, although this call can fail (and return false) under certain conditions.
For example, you cannot set focus on a control from a page’s constructor; it’s too early. You can,
however, call it from a page’s Loadedevent.

Answer (score 0):

The way that it worked best for me on the phone was, if I wanted to focus on a particular textbox when the page loaded:

```
private void OnPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher dispatcher = Deployment.Current.Dispatcher;
    dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => EnterLocationTextBox.Focus());
}
```

or if I just wanted it at a certain point. Just repeat these two lines:

```
Dispatcher dispatcher = Deployment.Current.Dispatcher;
dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => EnterLocationTextBox.Focus());
```