# Windows phone Text Boundaries

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, text, bounds

I'm starting the development of a Windows Phone application and I can't find out how to get a rectangle selection on a textblock.
I'm looking for the exact same information as the getTextBounds(...) method gives in Android ([getTextBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextBounds%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect%29))

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 doesn't have any direct way to measure text. The closest you can get is to create the TextBlock and then check its ActualWidth.

```
TextBlock t = new TextBlock();
t.Text = "Lorum ipsum";

Debug.WriteLine("Text {0} {1},{2}", t.Text, t.ActualWidth, t.ActualHeight);
```

If you update to Windows Phone 8.1 then you can interop to DirectWrite to measure text, but DirectWrite is not available on Windows Phone 8.0. Win2D has measuring text on [the backlog](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D/wiki/Backlog), but it's not there yet (and won't support WP8).

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any chance, asking about `focusing` the `Textbox`:

```
//For your textbox
private void yourTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  (sender as TextBox).Text = string.Empty;
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967208/programatically-set-focus-to-a-textbox-in-windows-phone?rq=1)

Or else try using the [Control.Focus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702161.aspx).

Comment: That's not what I want to do. I want to get the smallest rectangle in which my text could fit. The bounds of this text in other words.

Comment: if you could provide a screenshot or something of what you need?

Comment: I'm looking for some metrics like this : http://www.csharphelper.com/howto_wpf_measure_formattedtext.png

Comment: actually, it's exactly what you can find on the following link, but I'm not using .NET https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwf9s90b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx